Calculate total count based on time span
Added a new data set because it's not producing the intended output.
If the cadence values are different, even if the dates overlap the records must be separate.
If an order for the same dose and cadence value (including nulls) starts on the same day or the next day (+or-1 day) the record should continue.

expected additional dataset output:

current output for patid=103 with the current code:

previous test data

Result data expected:
How to figure out the total number of doses within a time span given to a client as dose are being added and stopped. In some cases, new start dates, and end date may be created. as explained for patid=147

There are 3 orders for 12.5 MG dose active on 10/15.
One is only for 10/15 the other two continue until 10/14/2020.
Another order for 25 mg begins on 11/4/2019 and continues until 11/3/2020)

The logic is if e,g 01/01/2024 to 01/07/2024 a patient receives 25mg dose and he receives an additional 30 mg dose from 01/04/20204 -01/17/2024. That means an accurate count with new assigned date will be 01/01/2024-01/03/2024=25 mg 01/04/2024 -01/07/2024 = 55mg (25+30) mg, then from 01/08/2024-01/17/2024 =30mg because the client has stopped taking the 25 mg dose.
drop table #prescribed_dose
drop table #prescribed_dose_Result
    CREATE TABLE #prescribed_dose (
     [patid] [varchar](20) NULL
    ,[Generic_Name] [varchar](256) NULL
    ,[Route] [varchar](50) NULL
    ,[s_date] DATE
    ,[e_date] DATE
    ,[Ordered_Dose] [numeric](15, 2) NULL
    ,[cadance_value]  int--if not null
    --,[ext_date] DATE--end date plus candance value


    )

    INSERT INTO #prescribed_dose
    VALUES
    ('125','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-07-21','2016-07-25',100.00,14)
    ,('125','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','2016-07-21','2016-07-22',234.00,null)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-01-27','2016-03-01',12.50,14)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','0','2016-02-03' ,'2016-02-04',25.00,null)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-02-17','2016-03-01' ,25.00,14)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-09',25.00,null)

    ,('141','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-05-14','2016-07-26',250.00,30)
    ,('141','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-08-05','2016-08-10',100.00,14)
    ,('141','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','2016-08-05','2016-08-06',234.00,null)
    ,('141','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-05-25','2016-07-26' ,50.00,14)
    ,('141','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-10',25.00,21)
 
    ,('147','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','2019-10-03','2020-10-02',234.00,30)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-10-15','2019-10-15',12.50,14)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-10-15' ,'2020-10-14',12.50,14)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-10-15','2020-10-14' ,12.50,14)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-11-04','2020-11-03',25.00,14)

    ,('7','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-03-12','2017-03-11',100.00,31)
    ,('7','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-03-14','2017-03-13',100.00,30)

    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-01-12','2017-02-01',25.00,null)
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-02-01','2017-07-20',25.00,null)
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-07-20','2018-07-18',25.00,null)
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2018-07-18','2019-07-18',25.00,null)
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2020-08-21','2021-08-21',25.00,null)          
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2021-08-21','2022-08-21',25.00,null)


    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-01-13','2017-01-31',25.00,null)
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-02-01','2017-04-11',25.00,null)
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-04-13','2018-04-13',25.00,null)
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2018-04-13','2018-07-18',25.00,null)
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2018-07-18','2019-07-18',25.00,null)          
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2021-09-26','2022-09-26',25.00,null)




    ------desired result

    CREATE TABLE #prescribed_dose_Result (
    [patid] [varchar](20) NULL
    ,[Generic_Name] [varchar](256) NULL
    ,[Route] [varchar](50) NULL
    ,[s_date] DATE
    ,[e_date] DATE
    ,[Ordered_Dose] [numeric](15, 2) NULL----Total Dose - if multiple orders for same drug overlap,with differnt cadence- add them together
    ,[cadance_value]  int--if not null
    --,[ext_date] DATE--end date plus candance value
    )

    INSERT INTO #prescribed_dose_Result
    VALUES

    ('125','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-07-21','2016-07-25',100.00,14)
    ,('125','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','2016-07-21','2016-07-22',234.00,null)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-01-27','2016-02-16',12.50,14)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-02-17' ,'2016-03-01',37.50,null)
    ----- 37.50 includes the order for 12.5 MG that begins on 1/27 and ends on 3/1 
    --and the order for 25 MG that begins on 2/17 and ends on 3/1.
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-09' ,25.00,14)
    ,('125','risperiDONE Consta','O','2016-02-03','2016-02-04',25.00,null)

    ,('141','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-05-14','2016-07-26',250.00,30)
    ,('141','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-08-05','2016-08-10',100.00,14)
    ,('141','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','2016-08-05','2016-08-06',234.00,null)
    ,('141','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-05-25','2016-07-26' ,50.00,14)
    ,('141','risperiDONE Consta','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-10',25.00,21)
 
    ,('147','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','2019-10-03','2020-10-02',234.00,30)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-10-15','2019-10-15',37.50,14)
    ---There are 3 orders for 12.5 MG dose active on 10/15. 
    --One is only for 10/15 the other two continue until 10/14/2020.
    --Another order for 25 mg begins on 11/4/2019 and continues until 11/3/2020.
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-10-16' ,'2019-11-03',25.00,14)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2019-11-04','2020-10-14' ,50.00,14)
    ,('147','risperiDONE Consta','R','2020-10-15','2020-11-03',25.00,14)


    
    ,('7','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-03-12','2017-03-11',100.00,31)
    ,('7','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','2016-03-14','2017-03-13',100.00,30)

    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-01-12','2019-07-18',25.00,null)
    ,('103','risperiDONE Consta','R','2020-08-21','2022-08-21',25.00,null)

    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-01-13','2017-04-11',25.00,null)
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2017-04-13','2019-07-18',25.00,null)        
    ,('121','risperiDONE Consta','R','2021-09-26','2022-09-26',25.00,null)





    select * from #prescribed_dose
    order by patid,Generic_Name,S_Date,Route

    select * from #prescribed_dose_Result
    where patid in ('103','7','121')
    order by patid,Generic_Name,S_Date,Route


You need to explain the logic clearly. Please consider edit and add more details to the required logic. Also include your current attempted query. Also tag the version of SQL Server you are using

Also contrary to comments on result there's no  1/27 date in your #prescribed_dose

So what exactly is the question?

Your question would be clearer if you showed your desired results using table markdown so we can see them without having to run the sql

I threw this together. It might be useful to you but I won't get involved more without a better description of the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/IJbuSbUn

This is more robust: https://dbfiddle.uk/vx8uJj1i I'm not sure if cadance values are relevant to the problem though and there are probably other hidden requirements as well.

@shawnt00 the cadence value is not that important

@shawn, I like Your fiddle. The unclear requirements of this question set aside, it solves a gaps-and-islands-like problem in a very perfomant way.

@shawn, Yet, if I add another row to the base data, that has the same begin and end date, it doesn't make it into the result. I tried this in Your fiddle for one of the patients for which I added such a row: https://dbfiddle.uk/VMimKR4q.

@DerU It does appear that that's a valid scenario. I think the way to account for that is to adjust the end dates one day forward.

@shawnt00.I added to the data set because I was updated that the cadence value is needed. Your code is working for the first data set but is returning more data result for the added data set . Can you please look into this ---Rules:    If the cadence values are different, even if the dates overlap the records must be separate.
If an order for the same dose and cadence value (including nulls) starts on the same day or the next day (+or-1 day) the dose should continue and not be added.

Use a union to combine all the dates into a single list. Start dates will be treated as increments to the total dosages while end dates will decrement. Since these values will offset each other, the total dosage at any point is the running total calculating from the beginning. (Don't use float as the column type as it might not reliably cancel out.)
with dates as (
    select *, s_date as dt, 1 as direction, ordered_dose as dose_change
        from #prescribed_dose union all
    -- adjust end dates so they take effect the following day
    select *, dateadd(day, 1, e_date), -1, -ordered_dose from #prescribed_dose
), nodes as (
    select patid, generic_name, route, dt,
        sum(direction) as lvl, sum(dose_change) as daily_dose_change
    from dates
    group by patid, generic_name, route, dt
), cumulative as (
    select *,
        sum(lvl) over (
            partition by patid, generic_name, route order by dt) as total_orders,
        sum(daily_dose_change) over (
            partition by patid, generic_name, route order by dt) as total_dose,
        lead(dt) over (
            partition by patid, generic_name, route order by dt) as next_dt
    from nodes
)
select patid, generic_name, route,
    dt as s_date, dateadd(day, -1, next_dt) as e_date, total_dose, total_orders
from cumulative
where total_orders > 0
order by patid, generic_name, route, dt;

https://dbfiddle.uk/QSlWX071

Nice query. Nice concept.

@shawnt00 I added more data set

@shawnt00 the code is not working for patid = 103 and 7.Patid is a time span of continuous date, while for patid=7 its the same generic name but there is a break in time span. Hence it should only produce 2 records but its producing a record in the middle between the seperate time span(3 records) and summing up the dose

@Drdre01 You originally said the cadance_value didn't matter. Now you've changed the  entire question with a new requirement to consolidate adjacent ranges.

@shawnt00 that was my understanding at 1st but the BA later updated me that the  cadance_value is needed.

What happens if say the dosage is increased on the day before the lower dose ends? You probably need to spell all the scenarios out.

@shawnt00 If you are asking if the dose can change on an order, no, orders do not change. It is unlikely by adding a new order before discontinuing the old order, but it is possible that they try a larger dose, and there is negative side effects, and so they drop them down to a lower dose by discontinuing all the orders and entering an order for the lower dose. So, in summary it's a new request.

@shawnt00   https://dbfiddle.uk/Yv7Q4DgL   The route was not important but the cadence value. So, I replace the route with the cadence value. The goal is really the dose. But the results are still the same. I need 103 and 7 to be continues for the same dosage within adjacent date span.

@Drdre01 You can't go changing the question/requirements and expect people to jump to do your work. Apparently you need to blend your input ranges prior to feeding into the original query. Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/gI5vVcT6 I don't promise it will work with any other weird scenarios though.

@shawnt00 .Thank you so much It is working for almost all the scenarios except for patid=147.It's returning 4 records instead of 5 records

@Drdre01 That's exactly the kind of stuff I'm talking about. You need to state in plain English when the dosages should be "stacked" (my word) vs "continued" (your word.)

@shawnt00.It is stacked when the same dose or different doses falls within the same time span. It is continuous even when they are the same dose but start date to end date are equal or adjacent. Example of stack is if e,g 01/01/2024 to 01/07/2024 a patient receives 25mg dose and he receives an additional 30 mg dose from 01/04/20204 -01/17/2024. That means an accurate count with new assigned date will be 01/01/2024-01/03/2024=25 mg 01/04/2024 -01/07/2024 = 55mg (25+30) mg, then from 01/08/2024-01/17/2024 =30mg because the client has stopped taking the 25 mg dose.

@Drdre01 There is a record/order with the same start and end date. That allows it to meet both criteria. Explain how these can be differentiated. I understand the general ideas behind what you're doing but you're failing to account for cases like this.
